# Setting holdout from python does not update render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When I run this while cycles is set in viewport does not take effect:

```
for a in bpy.data.collections:
    for item in a.objects:
        if item.type == "MESH":
            item.cycles.is_holdout = True
            print(item.name)
```

Any hints on how to force cycle update?

Comment: I use: `obj.data.update()`